# Clean foam residue off windows

Tags: repair, insulation, windows, cleaning

In a new construction home, when we moved in there is this residue on the interior window framing. This is not spray insulation, but looks like there was some type of foam on the windows itself during shipping (?)

We've tried several things to get this gunk off - goof off, goo gone, acetone, etc.

The builder at one point said they might have to just replace the windows or try some special type of paint. I don't think they are going to come through on this.

See the photo below. There was some actual foam there at some point we mostly scrapped off - if I recall correctly, it was more like upholstery foam then some construction foam in touch and appearance. We also see this in a few other spots on this set of windows, but this is the biggest, uggliest area.

[image]

Comment: Keep hounding the builder to fix/replace the window.  Is there a developer you can complain to about this? Sometimes they are more concerned about bad press that the builders.

Comment: What is the underlying material? Painted wood? PVC?

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate I am not sure, they are Andersen windows - they don't feel like wood, but i can't tell if that i just the coating.

Comment: My thought is that (if the builder lets you down), you might try mechanical removal -- plastic razor blades, scraping, sanding, etc. That's bad, though, if it's a factory finish on metal or if it's plastic. If it's wood, it's relatively easy to fix.

Answer (score 1):

That is most likely expandable foam that is used to seal air spaces. It has VERY sticky and can even bound with some plastics. It is very hard or impossible to completely remove and it will likely either need to be replaced or some cover-up applied (I have not heard of this or know of what could be done)

Your builder almost surely wants you to just go away. What do they have to gain from fixing it? Your future business? It is VERY common for contractors and builders to ignore you unless you continue to press HARD. This should be addressed by them, after all, you paid for this to be correct and you did not receive a credit for this poor condition, you should NOT HAVE TO LIVE WITH IT. If they start a pattern of vagueness / no commitment or give a longer time frame before they can address it (pretty much anything other than doing it now) then they are putting you off hoping that you will give up. Don't give up. Get legal help if you need to.

Comment: "Listen, Mr. Builder, getting lawyers involved in this would be so ugly and expensive for both of us..." is likely to get action within a week. As would "Hey, Mr. Builder, I don't want to have to call Bulldog Reporter from QXYZ's community reporting group..." Bad publicity on local TV is even worse than legal expenses.

Answer (score 1):

I would not care what it is it is SLOPPY work , contact the BBB , and your state’s contractor board, first this looks like spray foam I agree with others but SLOPPY. Is an understatement! Cutting any foam out . Sealing with a shellac primer and repainting will cover the discoloring, make the contractor bite the bullet. Today’s requirements for new builds in my state don’t even think about spray foam! 
(Maybe for the last 20 years on new residential) curious to know your state and if the “contractor” is licensed.